# Populate view model DateTime properties with values using DateTimePicker?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, datetime, google-analytics

I been trying to get around this for sometime now but I simply don't get it. For my view I use two `DateTime` properties `StartDate` and `EndDate` which isn't providing any values atm. I also have a DropDownList and a submit button. In the DropDownList the user are able to select a report from Google Analytics and when he the user click the submit button the Report from Analytics is displayed with Google Charts API.

However when sending my query with the method `CreateGAStatisticsReport` in the controller to Analytics I need a `StartDate` and an `EndDate`. The idea is that the user choose anny dates with the help of the datePicker in the view, when clicking submit button these dates are passed to the `CreateGAStatisticsReport` as start/endTime values forming the report.

This is the view:

```
@model GAStatisticsListModel

@using Nop.Admin.Models.GAStatistics;
@using Telerik.Web.Mvc.UI;
@using Nop.Admin.Controllers;
@using Telerik.Web.Mvc.UI.Html;
@using System.Web.Mvc;
@using System.Linq;
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "GAStatistics";
    Layout = "~/Administration/Views/Shared/_AdminLayout.cshtml";
}


<h2>Google Analytics Statistic Reports</h2>


<table class="adminContent">
         <tr>
            <td class="adminTitle">
                @Html.NopLabelFor(model => model.StartDate):
            </td>
            <td class="adminData">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.StartDate)
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="adminTitle">
                @Html.NopLabelFor(model => model.EndDate):
            </td>
            <td class="adminData">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.EndDate)
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="adminTitle">
                @Html.NopLabelFor(model => model.GAStatisticsId ):
            </td>
            <td class="adminData">
                @Html.DropDownList("GAStatisticsId", Model.AvailableGAStatistics)
                <input type="button" id="GAStatisticsReport-Submit" class="t-button" value="@T("Admin.Common.Search")" />
        </tr>
</table>

<div class="t-widget t-grid">
  <table cellspacing="0">
    <thead class="t-grid-header">
      <tr>
        <th class="t-header" scope="col">
          <span class="t-link">Area Chart</span>
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div id="chart_div1" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<div class="t-widget t-grid">
  <table cellspacing="0">
    <thead class="t-grid-header">
      <tr>
        <th class="t-header" scope="col">
          <span class="t-link">Line Chart</span>
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div id="chart_div2" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<div class="t-widget t-grid">
  <table cellspacing="0">
    <thead class="t-grid-header">
      <tr>
        <th class="t-header" scope="col">
          <span class="t-link">Column Chart</span>
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div id="chart_div4" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    function onDataBinding(e) { <------ I tried validate Start/EndDate like this..
        var searchModel = {
                StartDate: $('#@Html.FieldIdFor(model => model.StartDate)').val(),
                EndDate: $('#@Html.FieldIdFor(model => model.EndDate)').val(),
            };
            e.data = searchModel;
    }

    $("#GAStatisticsReport-Submit").click(function () {
        if ($("select[name='GAStatisticsId'] option:selected").text() == "Visitors")
            drawChart()
    })

    google.load("visualization", "1", { packages: ["corechart"] });
    google.load("visualization", "1", { packages: ["treemap"] });

    function drawChart() {
        $.get('/GAStatistics/GetData', {},
            function (data) {
                var tdata = new google.visualization.DataTable();

                tdata.addColumn('date', 'Date');
                tdata.addColumn('number', 'Visitors');

                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    var dateStr = data[i].Date.substr(0, 4) + "-" + data[i].Date.substr(4, 2) + "-" + data[i].Date.substr(6, 2);
                    tdata.addRow([new Date(dateStr), parseInt(data[i].Visitors)]);
                }

                var options = {
                    title: "Antal unika besökare per datum"
                };

                var chart1 = new google.visualization.AreaChart(document.getElementById('chart_div1'));
                var chart2 = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div2'));
                var chart4 = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div4'));

                chart1.draw(tdata, options);
                chart2.draw(tdata, options);
                chart4.draw(tdata, options);
            });

    }

</script>
```

Sorry I'm new to this but I believe `EditorFor` might be Telerik implementation.

In the controller `CreateGAStatisticsReport` is meant to use `StartDate` and `EndDate` values from the model, convert these dates to string format `yyyy-MM-dd` and use these strings as `Date` parameters in a request to Google Analytics API. I use the model as parameter in `CreateGAStatisticsReport`.

The controller:

```
    //GET: /ShopStatistics/
    public ActionResult GetData(GAStatisticsListModel model)
    {
        return Json(CreateGAStatisticsReport(model), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

    public ActionResult GAStatistics()
    {
        return View(new GAStatisticsListModel());
    }

    public List<GAStatistics> CreateGAStatisticsReport(GAStatisticsListModel model)
    {
        var serviceAccountEmail = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx@developer.gserviceaccount.com";
        var certificate = new X509Certificate2(@"C:\Users\Desktop\NopCommerce\Presentation\Nop.Web\key.p12", "notasecret", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);

        var credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(
        new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(serviceAccountEmail)
        {
            Scopes = new[] { AnalyticsService.Scope.Analytics }
        }.FromCertificate(certificate));

        // Create the service.
        //Twistandtango
        var GoogleAnalyticsService = new AnalyticsService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credential,
            ApplicationName = "Twist",
        });

        //GAStatisticsListModel model = new GAStatisticsListModel();

        DateTime? startDateValue = (model.StartDate == null) ? null
                     : (DateTime?)_dateTimeHelper.ConvertToUtcTime(model.StartDate.Value, _dateTimeHelper.CurrentTimeZone);

        DateTime? endDateValue = (model.EndDate == null) ? null
                        : (DateTime?)_dateTimeHelper.ConvertToUtcTime(model.EndDate.Value, _dateTimeHelper.CurrentTimeZone).AddDays(1);

        string start = model.StartDate.ToString();
        model.StartDate = DateTime.ParseExact(start, "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

        string end = model.EndDate.ToString();
        model.EndDate = DateTime.ParseExact(end, "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

        var request = GoogleAnalyticsService.Data.Ga.Get("ga:xxxxxxxx", start, end, "ga:visitors");
        //Specify some addition query parameters
        request.Dimensions = "ga:date";
        request.Sort = "-ga:date";
        request.MaxResults = 10000;

        //Execute and fetch the results of our query
        Google.Apis.Analytics.v3.Data.GaData d = request.Execute();

        List<GAStatistics> ListGaVisitors = new List<GAStatistics>();

        foreach (var row in d.Rows)
        {
            GAStatistics GaVisits = new GAStatistics(row[0], row[1]);
            ListGaVisitors.Add(GaVisits);
        }

        return ListGaVisitors;
    }
```

Thought id also post a screen on the UI:

[image]

How can I populate `StartDate` and `EndDate` from the model and use these values in the controller - `CreateGAStatisticsReport`?

Sorry for all the text.

Thank you

Comment: So `StartDate` and `EndDate` are not populated in your `GetData` action? Is that the problem?

Comment: Well it should be populated in the view as there is a Calender/datetimepicker for start/endDate. I need to use these dt-values in CreateGAStatisticsReport when sending the querry to analytics api. GetData just draw the google charts based on what values i pass in the querry string.

Answer (score 1):

EditorFor is an ASP.NET MVC implementation to assist with the UI rendering of controls for model data. It auro-figures out the control to be rendered based on the data type. e.g. DatePicker for Dates.

To receive the submit action, you need to have a controller action with POST attribute and GAStatisticsListModel as the parameter. ASP.NET MVC will automatically construct the model parameter object and try to fill in as much data as possible.. including StartDate & EndDate. (called model binding)

so try doing this..

```
   [HttpPost]
   public ActionResult GetData(GAStatisticsListModel model)
   {
        // model should have the start & end dates.
   }
```

you can have 2 actions with the same name, differentiated by the HttpGet and HttpPost attributes.

Comment: I see, this is very insightful. Thank you for explaining. Iv'e only worked a little with http post and i now realize i have to look into this more in detail. Will try this and get back.

Comment: I believe i must redo a few things regarding model binding. I actually tried us9ing the [HttpPost] attribute before but the problem is the charts from google dosn't show at all when i click submit. If i remove [HttpPost] and press submit the charts will show. I able to display the charts using hardcoded dates atm.